# Git - Is there a way to view the number of lines committed by Author?

Tags: git

Does anyone know of a command or script that will output each author that has committed to the project followed by the number of lines they have contributed.

e.g. something similar to the following:

```
Author       Insertions   Deletions
Bob Dole     1240         409
Sarah J      481          140
Jim Helper   388          23
```

Cheers, Ben

Comment: This can probably be accomplished with a simple awk/sed script over the output of `git-blame`.  http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git shortlog -sne

Comment: I was about to mention this in my answer as well, you beat me to the punch.

Comment: That doesn't tell the number of line!

Comment: That's cool information, too, but prints the number of commits by author, not number of lines.

Comment: This is answering a completely different question. I'm not sure why it was voted up, but look at the other answers.

Answer (score 9):

This gives the line statistics for a particular author:

```
git log --author="_Your_Name_Here_" --pretty=tformat: --numstat \
| gawk '{ add += $1 ; subs += $2 ; loc += $1 - $2 } END { printf "added lines: %s removed lines : %s total lines: %s\n",add,subs,loc }' -
```

Comment: Can you extend your answer to output stats for all authors?

Comment: @mrgloom, this should work: `while read i; do git log --author="$i" --pretty=tformat: --numstat | { printf "$i: "; gawk ' { add += $1 ; subs += $2 ; loc += $1 - $2 } END { printf "added lines: %s removed lines : %s total lines: %s\n",add,subs,loc }' -; }; done < <(git shortlog -sne | sed 's/[^<]*<\([^>]*\)>/\1/' | sort -u)`

Answer (score 4):

A quick search dug up [GitStats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/), though that only generates HTML output.

**Update:** A bit more digging turned up [LookAtGit](http://github.com/mpdehaan/lookatgit), which seems more along the lines of what you were looking for.

**Second Update:** As mentioned on a comment to the original question, this can also be accomplished with git in conjunction with sed/awk. There's a nice example of how to do this [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486819/which-git-commit-stats-are-easy-to-pull) on SO.

Comment: But it is open source, so you could make it generate any output format you want...

Comment: True, though I'm assuming he wouldn't be asking for a pre-existing script if he had the time to whip one up himself.