# How do I show statistics for author's contributions in git?

Tags: git

I'm working with a team on a git project and I would like to see the contribution of each author in terms of lines written or lines edited etc... how can I show statistics for the authors?

Comment: That statistics has non sense in anyway, since you will get "contribution" to designer files that use to be auto-generated and longer (in lines of code) than most real changes. Also you can not take the number of lines as valid statistic of "contribution" since more lines of code usually are not the same as more work. I hope you are not going to measure your employees workload based on that random number!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could try [git-stats](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/git-stats) or use git command to [explore from the logs](https://coderwall.com/p/pek-yg/git-statistics-for-repo-per-author)

Refer following posts

1. Graphical Stats - [Generating statistics from Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828874/generating-statistics-from-git-repository?rq=1)
2. https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/3fb7ef0c0cbdb72412fc
3. [Which Git commit stats are easy to pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486819/which-git-commit-stats-are-easy-to-pull)
4. [PR-Count Github App](https://github.com/marketplace/pr-count) - Github ONLY. Thanks [@ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2923772/ben)

Comment: You can also try github app: PR Count https://github.com/marketplace/pr-count, if you don't like command line tool.

Comment: pr-count seems not to exist anymore. Also from GitHub, it sends to a bogus link

Answer (score 122):

As simple as:
`git shortlog -s -n`

Comment: This will count number of commits, not lines of code

Comment: `-s -n` can be combined together into `-sn`

Comment: @a.ch. to count the number of lines of code instead, you can use: 

`git ls-files | while read f; do git blame -w -M -C -C --line-porcelain "$f" | grep -I '^author '; done | sort -f | uniq -ic | sort -n --reverse`

Comment: @hartmut you should post a distinct answer

Comment: @hartmut this is great, but it doesn't count the lines that are deleted or lines modified by other people

Comment: @hartmut The command might to have two issues: (1) git submodules (2) spaces in filenames

Comment: @MartinThoma I don't think this has an issue with spaces in filenames.

Answer (score 27):

For those who prefer a more built-in solution, this script simply makes use of `git`, `grep`, & `awk`:

### Example

```
$ git user-stats
Email                           Commits         Files           Insertions      Deletions       Total Lines
-----                           -------         -----           ----------      ---------       -----------
john.smith@gmail.com            289             35              5361            3293            8654
joe.dirt@yahoo.com              142             17              2631            1756            4387
jack.bauer@fbi.gov              115             9               1407            1107            2514
```

```
$ git -C path/to/repo user-stats --since="1 week ago"
Email                           Commits         Files           Insertions      Deletions       Total Lines
-----                           -------         -----           ----------      ---------       -----------
joe.dirt@yahoo.com              20              3               83              634             717
john.smith@gmail.com            21              2               242             110             352
```

### Usage

```
$ git [git options] user-stats [git-log options]
```

### Show me the code

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# Show user stats (commits, files modified, insertions, deletions, and total
# lines modified) for a repo

git_log_opts=( "$@" )

git log "${git_log_opts[@]}" --format='author: %ae' --numstat \
    | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' \
    | grep -v '^$' \
    | grep -v '^-' \
    | awk '
        {
            if ($1 == "author:") {
                author = $2;
                commits[author]++;
            } else {
                insertions[author] += $1;
                deletions[author] += $2;
                total[author] += $1 + $2;
                # if this is the first time seeing this file for this
                # author, increment their file count
                author_file = author ":" $3;
                if (!(author_file in seen)) {
                    seen[author_file] = 1;
                    files[author]++;
                }
            }
        }
        END {
            # Print a header
            printf("%-30s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\n",
                   "Email", "Commits", "Files",
                   "Insertions", "Deletions", "Total Lines");
            printf("%-30s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\n",
                   "-----", "-------", "-----",
                   "----------", "---------", "-----------");
            
            # Print the stats for each user, sorted by total lines
            n = asorti(total, sorted_emails, "@val_num_desc");
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                email = sorted_emails[i];
                printf("%-30s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\n",
                       email, commits[email], files[email],
                       insertions[email], deletions[email], total[email]);
            }
        }
'
```

[View gist](https://gist.github.com/shitchell/783cc8a892ed1591eca2afeb65e8720a)

### Installation

Download the script, give it executable permissions, and stick it somewhere in your path. e.g.:

```bash
wget -O ~/bin/git-user-stats https://gist.githubusercontent.com/shitchell/783cc8a892ed1591eca2afeb65e8720a/raw/git-user-stats
chmod +x ~/bin/git-user-stats
cd ~/path/to/repo
git user-stats --since="1 week ago"
```

### Explanation

Basically it uses `git log --format="author: %ae" --numstat` (minus any empty lines or binary files) to generate output that looks like:

```
author: bob.smith@gmail.com
1       147     foo/bar.py
0       370     hello/world.py
author: john.smith@aol.com
7       6       foo/bar.py
author: jack.bauer@fbi.gov
1       0       super/sekrit.txt
author: john.smith@aol.com
2       1       hello/world.py
```

Each section that starts with `author: ...` is a single commit. The first column of `--numstat` is the number of insertions, and the second column is the number of deletions for that file.

It then walks over each line with `awk`. Whenever it hits a line that starts with `author:`, it stores the 2nd column of that line (the email address of the author for that particular commit) in the variable `author` and increments that user's total number of commits. For each subsequent line, it updates the number of insertions, deletions, and files for that user until it hits the next line that starts with `author:`. Rinse and repeat until it's done.

At the end, it sorts by the total line changes (insertions + deletions) and prints out all of the collected stats. If you wanted to sort by something else, you would simply replace the `total` array with the relevant array in the `asorti(...)` function. e.g., to sort by number of files, you would change that line to:

```
n = asorti(files, sorted_emails, "@val_num_desc");
```

**note** *any arguments/options will be passed to the `git log` command and can be used to filter results*
`git user-stats --since="2 weeks ago"`

#### A little more detail

The `git log` output is run through:

- `tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'` to normalize email addresses. My company capitalizes email addresses a la `John.Smith@TheCompany.com`, and depending on where / how a user is making their commit, that email might show up capitalized or all lowercase. This ensures that all instances of a particular email address are always grouped together regardless of capitalization.
- `grep -v '^$'` to remove empty lines that show up by default in the log output
- `grep -v '^-'` to remove the `--numstat` info for binary files, which looks like:
  `-      -  foo/bar.png`

Also, a cool feature of `git` that took me forever to find out is that, if you place an executable named `git-some-command` in a folder in your PATH, git will detect it, and you can use it via `git some-command`! This has the added benefit of being able to specify custom configuration settings on a per-command basis, e.g. `git -c color.ui=always some-command | sed ...`. So if you drop this script in, say, `~/bin/git-user-stats`, that's how you can use it via `git user-stats` as in the examples

Comment: If you see this error `awk: line 38: function asorti never defined` try installing gawk.  On Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install gawk`.  By default Ubuntu uses mawk for awk, not gawk.  `asorti` is a gawk extension.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore line ending changes and white space?

Comment: @AndrewH Oof, didn't realize I had `gawk` installed as a dependency. Thanks for the info, Andrew! I'll have to look into whether I can sort without it, else update the answer to reflect the dependency.

Comment: @kolobcreek How do you mean? As in, don't count files where the only modification was a whitespace change?

Comment: @kolobcreek Assuming you mean that you want to ignore situations where the only change a person made was whitespace, you can run it with the git log/diff option `--ignore-all-space`. Altogether that would be `git user-stats --ignore-all-space`. Other options to ignore various types of space changes are `--ignore-cr-at-eol`, `--ignore-space-at-eol`, `--ignore-space-change`, `--ignore-blank-lines`  You can mix and match those as you please. `git user-stats` will pass any arguments/options to the internal `git log` command, so anything `git log` accepts will work with this!

Comment: One small typo.  In the last line of the installation code you have `git user-stats` instead of `git-user-stats`

Comment: @jocassid If you add a script with the name `git-some-thing` to a directory in your PATH, you can run it with `git some-thing` :) When you run `git`, it will look through your path for all scripts/commands whose names are prefixed with `git-`. This has the added benefit of allowing you to set per-run options via e.g.: `git -C /path/to/repo -c user.name "John Smith" some-thing` when you run the script.

Comment: Thank you so much for this excellent tool.

Answer (score 8):

You should have a look to [repoXplorer](https://github.com/morucci/repoxplorer), an open source project I develop. It is able to compute stats for a project (a group of git repositories) as well as **for a contributor and a group of contributors**. It provides a REST interface and a web UI. The web UI provides various information like, for a given contributor:

- commits, lines changed and projects count
- date histogram of commits
- top projects by commits
- top projects by lines changed

But best is to have a look to the demo instance [here](https://repoxplorer-demo.okombu.com).

Here is a screenshot of the stats page of a contributor (stats are computed accross all repositories indexed by repoxplorer, but can be filtered for a specific project):

[image]

Comment: Can we use this for non-github projects?

Comment: Sure, it can be used with any git repositories. It is not tied to GitHub or other hosting platforms.

Comment: are there any instructions for that? I saw only github specific ones at least under "quickstart"

Comment: If you use the docker way, then follow the first step of the section https://github.com/morucci/repoxplorer#quickstart---use-the-repoxplorer-docker-container-to-index-a-github-organization in order to start repoXplorer. Then create a "projects.yaml" inside docker-data/conf/ by following https://github.com/morucci/repoxplorer#define-projects-to-index. The github helper is just a tool to read a github organisation from the github API to create a "projects.yaml". In your case you have to create the file manually.

Comment: Couldn't see how to configure it for anything but github

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest [Gitential](https://gitential.com). It measures:

- coding volume
- coding hours
- productivity
- efficiency

and provides an analytical interface to visualize them on multiple levels:

- projects
- teams
- repos
- developers

It also deduplicates author identities and filter suspicious commits to give a better picture.

Comment: this no longer exists