# Github repository statistics: Historical data on total contributors for each month for the past x months/years?

Tags: git, api, github, code-metrics

Imagine we have following GitHub repository: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch

On the right side of the page, you can see the `Used by` and `Contributors` count. Is it possible to get that information on a monthly basis, say for the past x months/years?

Working with the wayback machine doesn't seem perfect here, also because the data is incomplete, hence I wondered what mechanisms can be used to give you historical data.

Comment: https://github.com/sideshowbarker/git-monthly-committer-totals/ is a command-line tool I wrote specifically for generating historical monthly committer totals for any given git repo. Within whatever local clone of the repo you want data for, you can run the tool with `bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://sideshowbarker.github.io/git-monthly-committer-totals/git-ct.sh)" "" 6` (replace the `6` with whatever number of months of history you want output for).

Comment: @sideshowbarker The tool is great. Could you add it as answer so that others more prominently can see it and that it can be upvoted?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to call a [third-party tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42715893/6309), month by month, in order to get that kind of activity log.

For instance: [git-stats -s '1 June 2021' -u '30 June 2021'](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/git-stats)

Or: [`askgitdev/askgit`](https://github.com/askgitdev/askgit) can make queries, again for a given author/month, to your Git repository.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to get the statistics about a commit. There are two ways of doing this.

**Command Line method**

To get information about the commits in last one month from command line you can use following command

```
git shortlog --since=2021-01-06 --until=2021-01-07 -sn
```

Here the --since and --until is self explainatory, whereas -s is for summary and -n is for numbered.

On pytorch this gives output as follow. I have trucated the response to keep only 5 top authors.

[image]

Please note that you need the repository cloned on your local setup.

**GitHub API Method**

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.github.com/repos/pytorch/pytorch/commits?since=2021-01-06&until=2021-01-07' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json'
```

You can find the complete documentation about the API [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-commits).

There is no direct API to fetch the number of authors who have commited in last one month as the command line.

The response for the above API will need to be processed to get the count. Whereas, you can also add the parameter of author to get the commit history and effectively count of commits in last month by following API.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.github.com/repos/pytorch/pytorch/commits?since=2021-01-06&until=2021-01-07&author=myemail@email.com' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json'
```

Please note that the header `Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json` is recommended and not mandatory.

Depending on your exact use-case. We can use the right API's from the documentation.